Why is Taproot important to Ordinals?
I've learned SegWit, Taproot, Schnoor and Ordinals recently. I can understand all these terms. But I don't understand why people say Taproot makes Ordinals possible.
Taproot is actually the version 1 of SegWit. Before Taproot, we can only set version 0 when using SetWit. But I think the version 0 SegWit is already sufficient to implement Ordinals protocol? In the same way, we need 2 phases/transactions to inscribe some data:

Create a P2WSH transaction to commit a script. Just like what Ordinals does now (i.e., create a P2TR transaction to commit a script).
Create a transaction to reveal the script in the witness field. Just like what Ordinals does now.

In the script, I can still use the OP_FALSE OP_IF ... OP_ENDIF pattern to embed the inscription data into the script.
So we can still implement Ordinals protocol without Taproot. Why do people say Taproot makes Ordinals possible?

Related: How can taproot transactions manage to store so much data?

Thanks! Now I know that before Taproot, the P2WSH has a script size limit of 10000 bytes. Taproot eliminates this script size limit.
